# Mocking and modifying original function using native node mocking

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocking, pinojs

The latest versions of node have a built in test runner and [mocking capabilities](https://nodejs.org/api/test.html#mocking). I see the [function documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/test.html#mockmethodobject-methodname-implementation-options) for `mock.method()` reads that the default argument is the original method.

> implementation  |  An optional function used as the mock implementation for object[methodName]. Default: The original method specified by object[methodName].

Is there a way to access that original method to then modify it?

I tried creating a new instance of the method but this seems to trigger an infinite loop since I assume the mocked method is being triggered.

```
import * as Pino from "pino"

const logs: string[] = []
const dest = { write: (data: string) => logs.push(data) }

// Function in original src code just uses `Pino.pino(transport)`
mock.method(Pino, 'pino', (transport: any) => Pino.pino(transport, dest))
```